# Run a Big Query job from Node JS using user's oAuth credentials

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I have a web application using a NodeJS back end. The user authenticates using the Firebase signInWithPopup service with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery scope.

I want to run Big Query jobs using the user's credentials. If I use the NodeJS Big Query CLI I can authenticate and use it if I use service worker credentials made for the app, but I can't find a way to use the user's oAuth Access Token. If I use the REST API I can use the user's oAuth Access Token but the legacy version of SQL the API uses doesn't allow me to run the jobs I need to and returns SQL errors.

Is there a way to either use the user's oAuth Access Token with the Node CLI or a way to get the REST API to use the same version of SQL as the Node CLI?

I have tried adding token to the Node CLI like this:

```
 new BigQuery({
    projectId: tq.projectId,
    token: oauthAccessToken
})
```

As it looks like it might be able to do it (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/92119e3b23874263d9529283194a149b358b7c9f/src/bigquery.ts#L184) but it didn't work. Bard suggested this:

```
const BigQuery = require('bigquery');

const credentials = new BigQuery.GoogleCredentials({
  access_token: oauthAccessToken
});

const client = new BigQuery.BigQueryClient(credentials);
```

But GoogleCredentials isn't a command in BigQuery.

I have also tried setting the dialect and legacySQLDialectVersion in the REST API but they did not make a difference to the SQL errors I get.

The app is hosted on Google Cloud Run, so if there is a different way to authenticate which removes the Node CLI I am open to changing that too.

Comment: Could you try [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#node.js) code? Let me know if it's helpful or not.

Comment: Thanks @kiranmathew - it works with an account JSON file but I need to be able to use the current user's credentials

Answer (score 0):

I had also same question and I found the following REST endpoint. But you have to make sure that when you generate access token has `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery email profile` scope value. Hope this helps.

```
const accessToken = "TOKEN"
const query = "select 1;"

const bqResponse = await fetch(`https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/YOUR-PROJECT-ID/queries`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ timeoutMs: 5000, useLegacySql: false, query: query }),
        }
      )
```